# error in logcat fail3: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception

I am creating a page in Android that gets ID & Name and then inserts it to my database but I get this error in logcat.

**error in logcat is:**

> pass 1(854): connection success
>   pass2(854): connection success
>   fail 3(854): java.lang.NullPointerException

**my code is**:

```
public class Sampleactivity extends Activity {

String name;
String id;
InputStream is=null;
String result=null;
String line=null;
int code;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainprogram);
      final EditText e_id=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText e_name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button insert=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        insert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                id=e_id.getText().toString();
                name=e_name.getText().toString();


                insert();
            }
        });
}


public void insert()
{


ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
try{

    HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/insert.php");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
    is=entity.getContent();
    Log.e("pass 1","connection success");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.e("fail 1",e.toString());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "invalid ip address",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

try
{
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);   

StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
{
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}

is.close();
String  result=sb.toString();
Log.e("pass2","connection success");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.e("fail2",e.toString());

}

try
{

    JSONParser parser_obj=new JSONParser();
JSONArray   jsonArray=(JSONArray)parser_obj.parse(result);

    JSONObject json_data=new JSONObject();
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
    {
        json_data=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    }
    code=json_data.getInt("code");
    if(code==1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inserted Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sorry try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.e("fail 3",e.toString());
}


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_mainprogram, menu);
    return true;
}



}
```

I don't know the NPE was thrown. Any ideas ?

Comment: please post complete logcat

Comment: Also mark the line where your app crashes

Comment: I sent all logcat  because i used try and catch logcat shows this of them

Comment: nop, copy whats printed, not what you think we should see, what is the line of 854?

Comment: my error in try 3 and 854 isnot line

Comment: logcat hamine ke ferestadam dige  try 1,2 dorost kar mikone vali try shomare3 mire dar catch .errorhaye logcat ham baraye catch hast

Comment: alan fahmidam chimikhayd.monteha logcat stack trace ro tozih bedid

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray=(JSONArray)parser_obj.parse(result);   az in khat error migire

Comment: Please speak english.

Comment: @lmo really I don't what is NPE in try3 you do'nt have any idea about try number3?

Comment: For the third time: Please use e.getStackTrace() in your catchs and NOT e.toString() !, so you'll know where exactly the NPE is thrown. (And eventually, edit your initial post to include the full stacktrace)

Comment: I use stacktrace but I cant know what is NPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I khow what is problem
the problem  is in directory of php file
I used xampp and in htdocs ,I make folder and put php file in it,but its not true  and then put this code

```
> HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/insert.php");
```

I put php file in htdocs and make true
thanks and sorry about my problem

Answer (score 0):

Please use `e.getStackTrace()` in your `catch`s and NOT `e.toString()` !, so you'll know where exactly the NPE is thrown. (And eventually, edit your initial post to include the full stacktrace)

From what I see here, the NPE has a lot of chances to come from

```
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)parser_obj.parse(result); // right operand probably returns null
json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); // NPE is thrown
```

So, you've got to check if `jsonArray` is null, before using it. If I'm right, you will so have to check what's going on in `result`.

Comment: no I comment for and else in try 3 but again NPE has.is code in try 3 true?

Comment: Please use `e.getStackTrace()` in your `catch`s, so you'll know where exactly the NPE is thrown.  (And eventually, edit your initial post to include the full stacktrace)